# React-native app crashes on real android device

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, targetsdkversion

I am using react-native and currently started using redux and created one app but when I am running that app on the emulator it is working fine. Then I connected my mobile with android 6 through USB on that also it is working. But in other devices of Android 8 it is not working then I have changed targetSdkVersion to 28 then also it not working I am not getting what is the problem.

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting where is the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189080/discussion-between-andrew-and-ahtesham-shah).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the logs that [Ahtesham Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10684238/ahtesham-shah) provided in the above [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189080/discussion-between-andrew-and-ahtesham-shah).

```
2019-02-26 21:14:08.898 18689-18732/com.namaztiming E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.namaztiming/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit 
2019-02-26 21:14:08.898 18689-18732/com.namaztiming E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.namaztiming/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit 
2019-02-26 21:14:08.901 18689-18732/com.namaztiming E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8 
Process: com.namaztiming, PID: 18689 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.namaztiming/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit 
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:703) 
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:564) 
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:500) 
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:455) 
at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:18) 
at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:19) 
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:917) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

These suggest that the error is related to the following `react-native` [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814). Where `react-native` doesn't support 64-bit on Android.

There is a solution to the [problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814#issuecomment-462647801) that should be added to the `app/build.gradle`. The solution is to define the packaging options. This can be done like so.

```
android {
  ...
  // add the following packagingOptions 
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
  }
}
```

We also added the following to the `defaultConfig` in the `app/build.gradle`

```
ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
}
```

Then we cleaned the build.

[image]

Then restarted the app.

[image]

Comment: also added `ndk { 
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' 
}`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to add the following code to your app/build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64", 'armeabi'
    }
    packagingOptions {
           exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
           exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
           exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
           exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
    }

}
```

Comment: i got error ***'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'***